# Random images to (many) Image Views

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage

Sadly, I've got 36 UIImages and need to set a random image to each one.

My 6 images are named;

```
"Owl1"
"Owl2"
"Owl3"
"Owl4"
"Owl5"
"Owl6"
```

So, I want to set one random image to my 36 different UIImages. What is the best way to do this? An array? Here's my "try" so far.

```
var images: [UIImage] = [
UIImage(named: "Owl1")!,
UIImage(named: "Owl2")!,
UIImage(named: "Owl3")!,
UIImage(named: "Owl4")!,
UIImage(named: "Owl5")!,
UIImage(named: "Owl6")!
]

var randomUIImage = [Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4, Image5...]
        randomUIImage.shuffleInPlace()

randomUIImage[0].image = images[0]
randomUIImage[1].image = images[1]
```

But I realized this will not work, and I can't make this code for all 36 images... Anyone got a better idea? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip: you can use a range + map to create an array of your images.

```
let images = (1...6).map { UIImage(named: "Owl\($0)") }
```

`(1...6)` produces a collection of Ints, from 1 to 6 (including 6), and with `map` we create a new instance of `UIImage` for each Int, using them for the naming - since you named your images in order, it's convenient. It's like doing a loop and appending a new intance of `UIImage` to an array inside the loop, using an index for the naming: "Owl1", "Owl2", etc.

If you also have your `UIImageViews` in an array, you can assign the images with a loop.

Here's an example (I didn't verify on Xcode but it should be close to what you need):

```
for view in imageViewsArray { // the array with the 36 imageViews
    // a random index for the array of 6 images
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count))
    // assign the randomly chosen image to the image view
    view.image = images[randomIndex]
}
```

Comment: you're always 1-upping me eric ;)

Comment: Not familiar with that code, how can I use it to actually apply the images to the Image Views? :-)

Comment: BTW, you do know that I only have 6 images (Owl) and 36 Image Views in the storyboard? :-)

Comment: @RappeStegarn I've updated my answer. And yes, silly typo, of course. :p

Answer (score 3):

You can have an array of image names, and an array of images to hold them..

```
var imageNames:[String] = ["Owl1", "Owl2"....etc]
var owlImages:[UIImage] = []
```

Then randomly append the images

```
for index in 0...imageNames.count - 1 {
    var randomInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageNames.count)) //a random int from 0 to the size of your array
    owlImages.append(UIImage(named: imageNames[randomInt] //add the random image to the array
}
```