# Clean up code? (Xcode freezes at indexing)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, code-cleanup

I believe I have to clean up my code a bit, since Xcode for the first time started to freeze at "indexing" and I can't run my project. I think it's easy to do, but I don't know what way is the best. Got 36 UIImageViews...

```
@IBOutlet var Image1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image9: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image10: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image11: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image12: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image13: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image14: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image15: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image16: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image17: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image18: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image19: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image20: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image21: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image22: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image23: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image24: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image25: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image26: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image27: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image28: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image29: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image30: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image31: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image32: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image33: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image34: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image35: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Image36: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    let images = (1...6).map { UIImage(named: "Owl\($0)") }
    let imageViewsArray = [Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4, Image5, Image6, Image7, Image8, Image9, Image10, Image11, Image12, Image13, Image14, Image15, Image16, Image17, Image18, Image19, Image20, Image21, Image22, Image23, Image24, Image25, Image26, Image27, Image28, Image29, Image30, Image31, Image32, Image33, Image34, Image35, Image36]
    for view in imageViewsArray {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count)))
            view.image = images[randomIndex]
    }

}
```

Could I make an IBOutlet for all 36 images together? Or something like this? :-)

Info about the code in `ViewDidLoad()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793260/random-images-to-many-image-views).

Comment: I'm seriously suspecting that you HAVE to use UICollectionView or UITableView here for the code to be less ..this. Delete derived data (window->projects) and restard the xCode. It should work fine afterwards.

Comment: @FruitAddict Thanks! But I don't know how I can change the code to a UICollectionView :-)

Comment: Well, if you're showing 36 images on the screen they must be arranged in some form of grid or list. Instead of dragging 36 outlets you could populate 36 cells with those images, the code is way cleaner and extensible then.

Comment: @FruitAddict As you can see in my code, I'm bad. So I have to be given a concrete example in order to understand, sorry mate..

Comment: look up UICollectionView, its easy.

Answer (score 0):

As @FruitAddict said, an `UICollectionView` may be useful, depending of what you want to display of course. But if it doesn't fit your needs, you can still use an Outlet connection instead of an outlet :

[image]

Thus you can access every labels directly from labelCollection, which is an explicit unwrapped array of `UILabel`.

Also, in the gif, the second label is added to the collection outlet by draging it to the already existing outlet. The outlet is not replaced (as in a regular object), but instead the new label is added to the array.

**EDIT :**

As @nhgrif pointed out, don't rely on the order of the objects within the outlet collection :

> It's important to note that while many times the order within the outlet collection may coincidentally coincide with the order you dragged them in, Apple makes no guarantees about this and the order within the collection should not be relied upon.

You should consider this array as a set.

Comment: It's important to note that while many times the order within the outlet collection may coincidentally coincide with the order you dragged them in, Apple makes no guarantees about this and the order within the collection should not be relied upon.

Comment: Nice addition, I just added it.